# Campos não aparecem quando carrega arquivo .fr3 do Fast Reports

Tags: delphi-10, fast-reports

Tenho um relatório feito no *Fast Reports* versão 6.6.15 do Delphi 10.3. Neste relatório eu tenho dois *datasets*: **Pedidos** e **ItensPedido** (logicamente que estão conectados aos seus correspondentes componentes `TfrxDBDataSet`).

Ocorre que, quando o usuário final do sistema abre o arquivo `.fr3` desse relatório para personalizar o pedido, não aparece nada na parte Árvore de Dados -> Dados. E, com isso, o usuário não consegue arrastar novos campos que ele deseja para o *layout* do relatório.

Como resolver este tipo de problema? Não entendo esse *Fast Reports*, por padrão já deveria aparecer os campos para o usuário final sem problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Quando não esta aparecendo as variáveis conforme o esperado na árvore de dados ao abrir a tela de design do FastReport tenho três sugestões:

1. Verifique com duplo click sobre o componente `TfrxDBDataSet` e em sequência click no botão **Update** (lista de variáveis que serão demonstradas no relatório).
   [image: Imagem componente]
2. Em modo design certifique que todas as opções de dados estão marcadas no menu do FastReport (representa as variáveis que vc quer liberar para o cliente).
   [image: Design]
3. Identifique se o cliente esta abrindo o arquivo `.fr3` na tela onde os componentes `TfrxDBDataSet` estão sobrepostos caso contrario a árvore de dados esta representada desta forma.

[image: tree]

Caso seja a terceira situação. Sugestão de botão sobre tela para abrir o relatório.

[image: Relatorio]